# Mysql 2 SUM and different group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I need 2 different `SUM`, but not grouped by the same set.

The question is a bit odd, let's take an example. I have a query (let's say a classic select) which outputs this set of data:

```
+----+------+------+----+----------+
| id | t_id | o_id | lt | quantity |
+----+------+------+----+----------+
|  1 |   1  |    1 | 30 |      50  |
|  2 |   2  |   10 | 90 |      90  |
|  3 |   4  |   10 | 10 |      20  |
|  4 |   4  |   10 |  5 |      20  |
|  5 |   4  |    9 | 20 |      20  |
+----+------+------+----+----------+
```

Now for a brief explanation, `t_id` is a `fuel id`, `o_id` is an `order id`, `lt` is the amount of litres shipped, and `quantity` is the ordered quantity (in litres) for a given fuel.

So, if I explain line 1: The `order #1` is for 50 litres of `fuel #1`, for now only 30 litres have been shipped.

Line 2, 3 and 4: The `order #10` needs 90 litres of `fuel #2` AND 20 litres of `fuel #4`. 90 litres of `fuel #2` have been shipped, and 10+5 litres of fuel `#4` have been shipped. In other words: `order #10` needs 90+20 litres of fuel (any fuel), and 90+10+5 litres have been shipped.

Now, the tricky part is that I would like to `SELECT SUM(lt), SUM(quantity)`, `lt` grouped by `o_id` but `quantity` grouped by `t_id, o_id`. The expected output is:

```
+----+------+------+---------+---------------+
| id | t_id | o_id | SUM(lt) | SUM(quantity) |
+----+------+------+---------+---------------+
|  1 |   1  |    1 |     30  |           50  |
|  2 |   2  |   10 |    105  |          110  | <-- 90+10+5 | 90+20
|  5 |   4  |    9 |     20  |           20  |
+----+------+------+---------+---------------+
```

Any idea on how to achieve that? I hope my issue is well explained.

Thanks for your help.

PS: In fact, the whole question can be summarized by: Is it possible to have 2 aggregates grouped-by different values?

PS2: Here is an [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73cf73/1) giving almost the same set (as the first)

-- **EDIT** --

Shame on me... I didn't take the problem the right way, neither I clearly knew it. But thanks to @mendosi and his suggestions (which made me realize my mistake). Actually, I only need to `SUM` ordered quantities of fuel no matter which fuel, `SUM` shipped quantites of fuel no matter which fuel, that's all.

So here is the last [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73cf73/32/3), the last request is the final request I'm using.

Comment: are you sure your data i right. Your order 10 needs 90 + 20 + 20 liters or so says this sample data

Comment: Rather than seeing your current output, it would be better to show us the original table and query.

Comment: The set is right, just not detailed. The set is extract from a complicated query, `lt` comes from a `shipments` table that's why there can be 1 shipment or multiples to get the quantity (which is the quantity of the given fuel for the given order

Comment: Let me show you an Sqlfiddle

Comment: It is hard to understand how you would like the output to look. Could you show an example of expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Unfortunately, SQLFiddle isn't working or accepting my inputs... But trust me, you can create a single dummy table with these data, I'm sure the question will remain the same. The data are from 5 different tables, and the query uses an EXISTS in 3 inner joins, it won't be relevant to detail them

Comment: @mendosi I've edited my question to add the expected output. I need to `SUM`, but they shouldn't be gouped by the same set. `SUM(lt)` should be grouped by `o_id`, while `SUM(quantity)` should be grouped by the 2 columns `t_id, o_id`

Comment: @Max13 I can't quite match the sample output you provided with your description. It looks like the `SUM(quantity)` is only grouped by `o_id` in the sample because we can't distinguish between the quantity of fuel of different types.

Comment: @mendosi actually, the `quantity` belongs to the `orders` table. Line 4 and 5 of the 1st output are 2 shipments for the same order. So `quantity` refers to THE SAME line in `orders`, while `lt` are individual shipments. In the 2nd set, `lt` is summed between the same order, and quantity is summed when "same order AND same fuel". Is it better?

Comment: @Max13 Interesting looking at the SQLFiddle link you posted. I played around a bit and you could derive the final output from the source with a query like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73cf73/19/1

Comment: OMG... it's way more complicated than I expected... I'm working with `laravel`, I'll have fun implementing your query, thank you. Let me get back when it's done

Comment: @mendosi I've worked with your `sqlfiddle`, and because I'm working with `laravel` and it's ORM, I tried to paste the entire request and apparently the `id` #9 is still shown (even with a having). Is it a particular case your request doesn't handle? Or my surrounding request that has an issue (therefore I'm misusing the ORM somewhere) please? (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73cf73/24)

Comment: All that is necessary is to add `WHERE litres < quantity` and then use that query in an `EXISTS` or `WHERE IN`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73cf73/31/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer might be different if you were working from the original source rows, but if we assume that you're going to take the pasted table as a source, then the following query should get you the correct result:

```
Select a.o_id, 
    a.lt,
    b.quantity
  From (Select o_id, Sum(lt) As lt From Input As i Group By o_id) As a
  Join (
      Select o_id, Sum(quantity) As quantity
        From (
            Select o_id, t_id, Min(quantity) As quantity 
              From Input Group By o_id, t_id
             ) As c
        Group By o_id
       ) As b
    On a.o_id = b.o_id;
```

In the supplied input data, it looks as if the `quantity` field is repeated for all rows with the same `t_id` and `o_id` so I used a subquery to collapse all those rows to one and just get a single (`Min()`) value for `quantity` (subquery `c`). I then aggregated that by `o_id` in an outer subquery (`b`). Values for `lt` were summed across `o_id` in the third subquery `a`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to work. I don't really get how `distinct quantity` is correctly handled (There could be multiple times the same `quantity` and not referring to the same `o_id`, in that case it is already distinct values. Anyway, currently with my set of values, the output is correct, thanks a lot. BTW, there is no `MIN` or `MAX` they are just groupped values. As soon as I make sqlfiddle work, I will post my huge load of data.

Comment: @Max13 Now that you mention it... this is a problem in the case that one order has the same quantity for two fuel types. Let me know when you have sample data.

Comment: @Max13 I changed the query to handle the exceptions we described. Please test the new query for correctness.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've added the fiddle on my question